# Open a new window with Same session using jquery/C# Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, razor

I am trying to open a new window with same session as the current one. I wrote some code below but its no luck yet.

For example lets say i have a form with a label (Name), textbox (where the text goes in)
and a button when pressed takes me to a new window.

If i press the button it should open a new window with the same form elements and text in the textbox if it was put in before.

Also please note the new window must be opened as a new tab in the browser with the same state and same elements as in the previous browsers.

Anyone got an idea on this (using razor view engine or jquery/javascript) ? Thanks in advance.

```
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="textbox" value="nothing" id="text" />
  <input type="button" value="press me" id="submitButton" />    


  $(document).ready(function()
  {                      
    $('#submitButton').click(function()
    {
       var currentUrl=document.URL;
       window.open(currentUrl,"newWindow",300);
       event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to accomplish this by using modals instead of popup windows. Jquery UI has built in modal support: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

The advantage to this approach is that no data needs to be passed into a separate page. Your modal code would look something like this, with jQuery Dialog. This would go on the same page as your initial inputs:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <input type="text" id="popupText" name="popupText" />
</div>
```

and your click event would modified update the modal input and show the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(event)
{                      
  $('#submitButton').click(function()
  {
   $("#popupText").val($("#text").val());
   $("#dialog").dialog();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

This could definitely be cleaned up but I believe it'll do what you need pretty simply. The dialog can contain any html elements, so you can add a separate form if necessary.

Comment: Forgot to mention that another advantage of this approach is that it's much more tablet and phone friendly--iPads don't love popups and neither do most modern browsers.

Comment: Hi Brent. Thanks for your answer i understand what you are tryin to imply and i will definately take it into consideration. However the business requirement for me is that the new window should be opened as a new tab in the browser with the same settings. This is what i am aiming for.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'd suggest adding that to the question.